# Run/Group Tests by Category Attribute of NUnit in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I am trying to use the Category Attribute of NUnit with my Visual Studio Profession 2015. However, the attribute doesn't seem to be categorizing the Tests in the Test Explorer.

```
[Test]
[Category("ValidLogins")]
```

I tried this as:

```
[Test, Category("Login")]
```

But even that didn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using VS 2015 Update 2 or 3? Have you grouped tests by category? Is this NUnit 2 or 3? Are tests showing up in Test Explorer? Are you using Resharper?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Update 3. Nunit is 3. Yes the test did show up in Test Explorer without any change even after categorizing with the attribute. I am not using reshaper.

Comment: Can you right click on the tests in Test Explorer and group by category?

Comment: Thanks Rob, It worked. I never realized that there is an option to group by in Test Explorer itself. I had to use Group By->Traits to get the Test Cases to be grouped by category.

Comment: Excellent. Many people miss that, so I will write up the answer for others.

Answer (score 24):

By default, Visual Studio's Test Explorer Window groups tests by **Outcome** which groups by Passed, Failed and Not Run. Many people miss the options for changing the grouping.

You can **right-click on a group and select Group By**,

[image: Grouping Unit Tests in Visual Studio]

or there is a **grouping dropdown** in the upper left corner of the Test Explorer window.

[image: Grouping Unit Tests in Visual Studio]

Visual Studio groups tests by Class, Duration, Outcome, Traits or by Project. Traits map to NUnit's Categories.

Comment: Now there is a "Show Test Hierarchy" toggle left of the "Group By" button and if this is activated the other grouping options become unavailable.

Comment: I'd like to add that I had to run the test to update the tests tree. Maybe forth mentioning, because I saw the Group by option, but as everything is now updated on the spot, I thought it wasn't working. Using VS 2022 Community Edition.

Answer (score 1):

We can create Playlist and organize the tests by group.
Open Test Explorer, right click any test/or group of tests, add to Playlist, and save the Playlist to a file. then we can open one Playlist file and click to run it as a group.